# V4L2 Loopback: VLC can use it, but a web browser can't

Tags: firefox, video, chromium, ubuntu-20.04, v4l2

I have a bunch of USB 3 capture devices feeding OBS, and V4L2 Loopback to provide OBS's output as another video input.  (/dev/video99)  I want to use that output in an online meeting, but neither firefox nor chromium wants to use it.

Firefox doesn't ask at all until I close OBS, which isn't helpful.  When OBS no longer claims them, it gives me a choice of the original sources, and that works, but I want to use the produced feed from OBS instead.

Chromium is a little bit more helpful in that it displays an error message: "Video error: Could not start video source".  Like Firefox, it also gives me a choice of the original sources when OBS hasn't claimed them, and that works, but I want to use the produced feed from OBS instead.

Given that error message from Chromium, I *then* started VLC, opened the loopback device, and took this screenshot.  The left window is Chromium, the middle is VLC, and the right is OBS's own "projector".

[image]

So the loopback works, according to VLC, but two web browsers don't like it.  Why?

And how to use the loopback in an online meeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An update to either V4L2 Loopback or Chromium seems to have fixed it, at least for me.**

Don't know which it was, because they both had updates and now it works.  I can now start OBS first, to feed the loopback, and then Chromium recognizes that loopback straight away.

Original workaround is as follows:

---

Partial answer, [based on this forum thread](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/5186#issuecomment-605506403):

1. Start Chromium (Firefox fails at #4 below), and start the meeting.
   OBS should NOT be running yet.
2. Choose a camera (or other video source) that will absolutely **NOT** be needed in the meeting.
   (it will become unavailable later, as either Chromium does not release it, or OBS doesn't pick it back up)
3. Start OBS, and make sure that it's feeding V4L2 Loopback.
4. Now Chromium can see the Loopback, so switch to it.
   (Firefox just doesn't see it here)
5. Produce the video feed in OBS as usual, minus that one source that was needed to get the meeting started.

---

That works, but it's only a partial answer because:

- It makes one of the sources completely unavailable.
- It requires some manual steps that can't easily be scripted on system start.
  (yes, I could automate the mouse and keyboard with xdotool, but that's way too brittle)